# Parser String C# Function

Tags: c#

I need this function to be converted to alternative way to C #, I tried to find some similar function but without success.

Function in Pascal/Delphi

```
function Parser(Buffer,Start,Finish:string):string;
var
  PosStart, PosFinish:  Integer;
begin
  PosStart := Pos(Start, Buffer)+ Length(Start);
  PosFinish := Posex(Finish, Buffer,PosStart);
  Result := Copy(Buffer, PosStart, PosFinish - PosStart);
end;
```

example to use:

```
kappa := 'test 0646944 but';
Parser(kappa,'test','but');
```

This function returns what is between the two camps

```
Result: 0646944
```

Any1 alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods work:

```
var buffer = "test 0646944 but";
var start = "test";
var finish = "but";

var parsed =
    buffer
        .Substring(
            buffer.IndexOf(start) + start.Length,
            buffer.LastIndexOf(finish) - buffer.IndexOf(start) - start.Length);

// OR

var parsed =
    Regex
        .Match(buffer, Regex.Escape(start) + "(.*?)" + Regex.Escape(finish))
        .Groups[1]
        .Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.IndexOf => Pos

string.LastIndexOf => PosEx (I think)

string.Substring => Copy
```

Now try writing some code and ask again if you get stuck

Comment: Even Wikipedia does not cover PosEx - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(string_functions)

Comment: I would rather bet on `PosEx` being `string.IndexOf(value, startIndex)`